# Query with datatables by passing custom parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I try to get data from a database and display it on a datatable. This code works:

```
  tableTest = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: "/datatables/getSomething",
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    columns: [
      {data: 'a'},
      {data: 'b'},
      {data: 'c'},
      {data: 'd'}
    ],
    responsive: true
  });
```

But now I want to pass custom parameters, e.g. `myCustomParams = ["foo", "bar", "top"]` to the request so I can query custom data.

```
  tableTest = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "/datatables/getSomething",
      type: "POST",
      data: myCustomParams
    },
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    columns: [
      {data: 'a'},
      {data: 'b'},
      {data: 'c'},
      {data: 'd'}
    ],
    responsive: true
  });
```

In `getSomething()` I would then take the parameters (i.e. `["foo", "bar", "top"]`), query the dataset I want, and then return it back.

But I would only get the error

> invalid JSON response.

I looked up that error. I debugged, I looked into Developer Console-> Network-> response and saw that instead of a return value, I get the whole page back. Is there a syntax error I'm missing?

Comment: Open the route `/datatables/getSomething` in your browser directly and see what it returns. It should output JSON in any case (even when there was an error). This question seems to be not related to JavaScript but to whatever language you are using on the server.

Comment: @feeela I'm using nodeJS. So, it is JS. When I go to datatables/getSomething on my browser I see as a response not a JSON file, but the whole HTML code of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per jquery documents the data should be a plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

you are directly passing an array , try to wrap that inside an object {},

including the example as per the suggestion by OP

```
 ajax: {
  url: "/datatables/getSomething",
  type: "POST",
  data: { "myRequest": myCustomParams } 
}
```

Comment: You should not edit another answer with your code @thadeuszlay. The answerer cannot accept your edit FYI, it goes to a queue of trusted users to check, which is where I saw this. If you want to answer, you can answer your own question

Comment: @Liam ok, I thought I would do him and others a favour by elaboriting on his answer and accepting it. Ok. I answered my own question.

Comment: If you want to help and this answer was useful, upvote it? @thadeuszlay

Comment: @thadeuszlay : glad that you got the resolution using the answer above, you can accept it if you think it helped.

Comment: @Liam it did help. But I needed time to figured out myself. Having an example would be more clear to me. But ok. @ Deep I will. :)

Comment: Included the example  Cheers, keep coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example and it works

```
tableTest = $('#example').DataTable({
ajax: {
  url: "/datatables/getSomething",
  type: "POST",
  data: function ( d ) {
       d.myCustomParams = myCustomParamsValues;
  },
},
serverSide: true,
processing: true,
columns: [
  {data: 'a'},
  {data: 'b'},
  {data: 'c'},
  {data: 'd'}
],
responsive: true
});
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the accepted answer didn't work for me and this did. Here is the official documentation about it in the dataTables docs: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Answer (score 0):

This way the data is passed to the router `getSomething()`

```
  tableTest = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "/datatables/getSomething",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "myRequest": myCustomParams
      } 
    },
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    columns: [
      {data: 'a'},
      {data: 'b'},
      {data: 'c'},
      {data: 'd'}
    ],
    responsive: true
  });
```